# Minimize the app after clicking the option like background in phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova

Minimize the app after clicking the option in App page like background in phonegap.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i got the answer for this after research for the plugin.Solution is,There is a one plugin called katzer-Background-mode,this is the solution after that added one plug in called "Backbutton".

In this we have,navigator.plugins.Backbutton.goHome(); Event is there.